# Refreshing A CollectionViewSource On A Button Click?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource

While learning WPF, as I started with developing a User Interface for a sample database like NorthWind as at [Microsoft's VS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-with-wpf-and-entity-framework-6?view=vs-2019), I came up with a **View Refreshing Code Piece** like:

```
custViewSource.View.Refresh();
```

but I realized that if a change to the data to the same database is made I couldn't load the change upon adding the same line like above to a button click event?

Let's assume I start debugging the said project, but at the same time, *while the said project is running*, I change the name of a Customer via SSMS or Access Front-End linked to the said DB of Northwind, then clicking the said new button and firing the:

```
custViewSource.View.Refresh();
```

doesn't reflect the new name?

The reason plus solution I wan't to know about the same is that what if a single database is being shared between users then if a record has been updated by one, how to notify the other user upon clicking a button and not carry out the same task again?

I am totally new to the WPF's magnificient World.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Refresh()` on an in-memory view doesn't query the database for new data. You need to issue the SQL commands yourself somehow, for example the same way as you did when you initially populated the `CollectionViewSource`.

If you are using Entity Framework, you could call `ToList()` on the `DbSet` and set the `Source` property to the new list of items returned from the DB:

```
custViewSource.Source = context.Customers.ToList();
```

There is no connection between the `CollectionViewSource` object and the remote database really. The view only contains the data that you populated its source collection with (this data may come from a database but the view doesn't really care) and it's your reponsibility to write code that updates this data as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response mm8.
However, as you can see in the said sample by MS the local copy is set at the initialization stage or at the windows load event how to do the same at btn_click event? i.e. in other words refresh/reload entire view again?
Sure do appreciate your clarification any how.

Comment: @FarazAhmedQureshi: If you are using EF, you could just call `ToList()` on the `DbSet` and set the Source property to the new list of items returned from the DB: `custViewSource.Source = context.Customers.ToList();`.

Comment: @FarazAhmedQureshi: Did you try this?

Comment: Yep! But did not work out!
The only way I have yet found is to close and reload the said form to refresh the data source. While assigning the same code on a button lick event too doesn't work.